# Using RabbitMQ with Celery in Django post_save

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I am applying asynchronous task handling using `Celery` on my Django Project.

My project's logic:,

- from frontend side, there is a table with rows each having an `upload button`. User clicks on it and a `payload` is sent to backend containing a url that contains a file.
- File is recieved in django views. And saved into database, table `Run`. Immediately object is saved a `post_save signal` is triggered to run a celery task.
- The task to be performed is, fetch a list of runs with specific status. For each run, perform a task of downloading the file.

I would like to perform this asynchronously in case there is more than one run. Keeping in mind user can click upload for more than one row from frontend.

I am setting up `RabbitMQ` as my broker. I have `rabbitMQ` installed and running. I have set the `CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqp://localhost'` too in settings.py. I am a little lost on what I should do next in my configurations, could I get some guidance. I think I need to configure celery worker on my tasks.

Below is my code so far :

views.py #view that saves to database

```
class RunsUploadView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RunsURLSerializer

    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        crawler_name = self.request.data.get('crawler')
        run_id = self.kwargs.get("run_id")
        run_url = self.request.data.get("run_url")

        run = Run()
        run.name = f"{crawler_name}_{run_id}"
        run.run = run_id
        run.url = run_url
        run.save()

        return Response(model_to_dict(run))
```

models.py # run is saved to table Run then a post_save signal is triggered.

```
from django.db import models


class Run(models.Model):
    UPLOAD_STATUS = (
        ("Pending", "pending"),
        ("Running", "running"),
        ("Success", "success"),
        ("Failed", "failed"),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    run = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=UPLOAD_STATUS, default="Pending")
    started_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    done_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

signals.py #handling the post_save logic after save()

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from main.models import Run
from main.tasks import DownloadRun


@receiver(post_save, sender=Run)
def download_file(sender, **kwargs):
    pending_runs = Run.objects.filter(status='Pending') #all pending runs collected, I would need to handle the runs asynchronously. 
    for run in pending_runs:
        run.status = "Started"
        run.save()
        DownloadRun(run)
```

Tasks.py #using a class because I am going to update with more functions.

```
class DownloadRun:
    def __init__(self, run):
        run_object = model_to_dict(run)
        self.run_url = run_object["url"]

        self.download_run()


    def download_run(self, dest_folder="runs"):
        ""Run file is downloaded from url""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way forward. I did not configure celery well.

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task #import shared_task decorator from celery
class DownloadRun:
    def __init__(self, run):
        run_object = model_to_dict(run)
        self.run_url = run_object["url"]

        self.download_run()


    def download_run(self, dest_folder="runs"):
        ""Run file is downloaded from url""

@shared_task 
def celery_task(run_id):
    DownloadRun(run_id)
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from main.models import Run
from main.tasks import celery_task #import celery_task from tasks.py


@receiver(post_save, sender=Run)
def download_file(sender, **kwargs):
    pending_runs = Run.objects.filter(status='Pending')
    for run in pending_runs:
        run.status = "Started"
        run.save()
        celery_task.delay(run.run) #call celery delay() to invoke the task (pass the unique key as parameter, could be id, in my case I chose the run)
```